# Disable Ms Excel in Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, reporting, reportviewer

hiii, 
 I am workin on .Net, C sharp.  In my ReportViewer, in the Export button, i only need pdf and want to disable MsExcel.
   i have made the changes to rsreportserver.config. 
   Is there anything else i need to do in my aspx page  or code behind...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible.  You cannot hide individual export options.  You can only hide the entire export option.  However, all is not lost.  You can create a button outside the report viewer and then handle the creation of the PDF in code-behind.